# Two nested divs are able to expand but not the parent

Tags: css

I have three DIVS in css which inside one DIV. I have two more other DIVS which I want when ever the value of the div inside parent div expand so the parent should make him self also expand which is not like this.

its just expanding the internal DIVS not the parent one here is my code:

```
<div style="background-color:#000; color:#FFFFFF;
width:444px; height: auto;">

    <div align="left" style="margin-top:10px; width:90px;
    height:auto; background-color:#FFF; float:left;
    color:#FF3; margin:5px 5px;">
        Lable:
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:10px; width:330px;
    height:auto; margin:5px 5px; background-color:#FFF; float:right; color:#FF3; border:solid 1px #000;">
        In here goes the value of the In here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the vae value of the
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: which is the parent `div` here and where does it close? Try giving individual ids to the `div` to make it clear

Comment: the first one is the parent and two others are child of it, its ended in the last part i mean the last </div> is the close parent div

Comment: try using `min-height` for the parent div instead of `height: auto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use overflow to parent element, because your child divs floated:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; background-color:#000; color:#FFFFFF; width:444px; height: auto;">
```

or use instead of

```
float:left;
```

for childs

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 1):

Done. here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vUbzx/1/) link
you need to add style

```
overflow:hidden
```

to parent div.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the floats.
Add this before ending the main div

```
<div style="clear:both;height:0px; width:0px">&nbsp;</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CbxGZ/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<div style="background-color:#000; color:#FFFFFF;width: auto; height: auto;position: absolute;">

<div align="left" style="margin-top:10px; width:90px;
height:auto; background-color:#FFF; float:left;
color:#FF3; margin:5px 5px;">
    Lable:
</div>

<div style="margin-top:10px; width:330px;
height:auto; margin:5px 5px; background-color:#FFF; float:right; color:#FF3; border:solid 1px #000;">
    In here goes the value of the In here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the vae value of the
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: </div> was hidden in indentation.